# converting Binary, hexadecimal, decimal in swift

Tags: swift

What i really want to know is what is the quickest way of converting this in swift

- Binary to Hexadecimal
- Hexadecimal to Binary
- Binary to Decimal
- Decimal to Binary

These are the conversation i am trying to do in swift

Comment: What have you tried? The algorithm is rather simple and there are actually library functions for that. Look at `String`/`Int` initializers. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2997127-init and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2924481-init

Comment: Take the pain and please search on google. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using native `String` and `Int` initializers:

```
extension String {
    func convertBase(from: Int, to: Int) -> String? {
        return Int(self, radix: from)
            .map { String($0, radix: to) }
    }
}

let binary = "000010001"
let decadic = binary.convertBase(from: 2, to: 10)
print(decadic)
let hexadecimal = binary.convertBase(from: 2, to: 16)
print(hexadecimal)
```